# Не отображается dropdown navbar в opera

Tags: opera, html, css

по ссылку fencing-zp.tk в шапке есть navbar с dropdown.

Во всех браузерах все отлично отображается, в opera не отображаются элементы меню.

подскажите что фиксить в css:
http://pastebin.com/vYNi1VeL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле **style.css** уберите у `.menu` свойство `content: ''`.